# How to totaly clear memory after remove object in C#

Tags: c#, memory

How to clear memory after using object?

A read a lot of question on this forum and every body say: Use `myObject=null` for delete your object.
Like this:

```
Car myCar = new Car();

//do stuff
myCar.horn();

myCar = null; // <-- DELETE
```

In my program, I am creating a lot of `Form` (`public partial class Myform: Form`).

Like this:

```
ArrayList listOfMyForms = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   listOfMyForms.Add(new Myform());
}
```

So.. I make 100 times object...

**BUT** if I delete all using remove method (call in for loop):

```
public void remove(Myform someForm)
{
    listOfMyForms.Remove(someForm);
    someForm = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

**I CAN SEE FULL MEMORY (20mb) in Visual Studio section: Diagnostic tools (Process monitor**

---

Before creating 100 forms is memory on 16mb.

After creating 100 forms is memory on 20mb.

**After clean all forms is memory on 20mb.**

---

So.. How can i free my memory?

I hope, you understand my problem. Sorry for my bad english :-)

Comment: You have to call `Dispose` on the forms first or use a `using` block.

Comment: @thehennyy I test with `Dispose()` and is same. No clean memory.

Comment: _"Use myObject=null for delete your object"_ - well no, it doesn't

Comment: If you using `GC.Collect()`, then your design is wrong

Comment: There is always an option of memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

I think this things will help you understand:

1. When objects are collected by `GC` the associated memory may or may not be freed to OS. `CLR` manages this process automatically.
2. When calling `GC.Collect()` it starts collecting and return immediately. It doesn't wait for finishing clean-up. To force your program to wait you need to call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` after `GC.Collect()`.
3. `Form` class is implementing `IDisposable` and is using unmanaged resources. For cleaning it you need to call `Dispose(true)`

FYI: In most cases you really didn't need to care about deleting objects manually, hope you know what are you doing.

Comment: You might want to add a call to `GC.WaitForFullGCComplete` as well and set the number of generations in `GC.Collect` to `GC.MaxGenerations`.

Answer (score 0):

use the bellow code.

```
public void remove(Myform someForm)
{
    someForm.Dispose(true)
}
```

Because forms use managed code. When using managed code you need to Implement IDisposable, and call Dispose method whenever you are no longer in need of the object.